# Transform class component to functionnal component in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I would like to make a parralax effect in react.

I have found a tutorial [on medium](https://medium.com/@relasine/building-a-parallax-header-in-react-301d0ab9fd96) that explains how.

My code is written in functionnal component, but in example it's class component.

Here's the example

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      offset: 0
    };
  }
return (
  <header 
    className='header-background'
    style={{ backgroundPositionY: this.state.offset}}
  >
    <section
      className='info-container'
      style={{ bottom: this.state.offset / 2 }}
    >
      <h1>Kevin Simpson</h1>
      <h3>Front End Developer</h3>
    </section>
  </header>
)
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.parallaxShift);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.parallaxShift);
}
parallaxShift = () => {
  this.setState({
    offset: window.pageYOffset
  });
};
```

I transformed it as to functional with my knowledges

```
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', setOffset(window.pageYOffset));
});
return (
  ...
  <svg style={{ bottom: offset }} className="border-circle" width={107} height={107} viewBox="0 0 107 107" >
  ....
```

Actually no `setOffset` is fired when I scroll, the event listener is not triggering events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three issues with your code

1. You are not removing your listener. This would cause memory leaks i.e performance issues.
2. The second parameter of addEventListener has to be a function definition rather than a function call.
3. useEffect executes everytime the component updates. To have the same functionality as componentDidMount add an empty array as the second parameter of useEffect so that its called only once after component initialization/mounting.

   useEffect(() => {
           window.addEventListener('scroll', () => setOffset(window.pageYOffset));
           return () =>  window.removeEventListener('scroll', () => setOffset(window.pageYOffset));
       },[]);

Writing your useEffect like this should work

Comment: thanks that helps, but I don't know when I update html elements dynamically they get above other superposed html elements, without animation it's under